# Is "Bible In a Minute" accurate?

Tags: bible

[The ***Bible In a Minute*** video by *Barats and Bereta*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ar_k8JjVWQA) has been enormously popular on YouTube, with 3.6 million viewers. The video quite literally goes through the Bible in less than a minute.

Obviously, the video leaves out a lot. But as **for what is included**:

1. **Is it accurate?**
2. **Is it enough?** Consider someone who knows nothing of the Bible but watches the video carefully over and over, even frame by frame. Can they learn enough of the Bible to become a Christian?

[image: A screenshot of the Bible In a Minute video by Barats and Bereta]

Comment: I was hoping YouTube embeds would work like on [Gaming.SE](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/how-can-i-beat-level-3-15-in-angry-birds/3749#3749). Obviously, they don't. *(I'm not suggesting to enable them, they're mostly no good here)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. For a <60 second list of excerpted chapter titles, sure.
2. Without any mention of what the "blood" mentioned at the cross acomplished or why Jesus was for sake -- without any mention of [faith](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1311/30) or [repentence](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/554/30)? No not hardly. Of course our salvation is not based on knowledge or amount of information we have anyway and God could choose to convict somebody of their sin and instill in them a faith that the things mentioned (resurrection was in there) were somehow on their behalf, but it's a bit of a stretch.

That is a Bible presentation, not a Gospel presentation.