# Scriptural basis of the "Notitia Assensus Fiducia" definition of faith?

Tags: reformed-theology, faith

I have read about the Reformed definition of faith - noticia, assensus, and fiducia. But what is the Scriptural basis for this definition of faith? Some point to Heb. 11:1, but I do not see the definition there, nor do I see it in 1 Thess 2:13.

Comment: A link to the terminology used would be helpful. At the moment, this question lacks both clarity and detail. Or some enlightenment as to what it means, perhaps ?

Answer (score 2):

Before attempting to answer your question, I first had to do some research to establish where “the Reformed definition of faith - noticia, assensus, and fiducia” came from.  Here is a partial quote from an answer given in 2014 by ShemSeger:

> The words notitia, assensus, and fiducia applied to faith originate with the Reformers of the 16th Century. Martin Luther argued that saving faith or true faith is a fides viva, a vital or living faith (Sproul, 2010, pg.47). This concept was further explicated by one of Luther's contemporaries, Philip Melanchthon. In 1521 Melanchthon first published his work, "Loci Communes Theologici," which was the first systematic explanation of Protestant theology, and condensed the thoughts of the Reformers and defined notitia, assensus, and fiducia as the three essential elements of saving faith. It is he that codified what the scriptures had taught, and it was from Melanchthon's work that these words first appeared in the context of faith (Israel, 2007, pg.233).  [What is the background of the words "notitia," "fiducia," and "assensus" and how do they relate to the biblical notion of "faith"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31589/what-is-the-background-of-the-words-notitia-fiducia-and-assensus-and-how)

I do not have access to Melanchthon’s work, but since you want to know what the biblical basis for the Reformed Protestant definition of faith is, let’s start with Hebrews 11:1 then move on to 1 Thessalonians 2:13.

***“Now faith is the substance of things hoped for, the evidence of things not seen” (Hebrews 11:1 KJV).*** Hebrews chapter 11 expands on the theme of faith, to show how men of faith trusted in God’s word and acted upon it even though they had not yet seen or received the promised blessings.  Theirs was an assured expectation of things hoped for and a certainty of what could not be seen.

First, they heard and understood what it was that God required of them – they received notice and they were acquainted with God’s word.  That is the meaning of ***‘notitia’***.

Second, they agreed with the word of God, assented to it and approved it.  That is the meaning of ***‘assensus’***.

Third, they trusted in God’s word, they had faith in God’s promises and they were confident of the outcome.  That is the meaning of ***‘fiducia’***.

The entire chapter of Hebrews 11 is a testimony to faith and presents evidence to show how faith is the product of hearing the word of God (whether it be spoken or read), understanding it and giving assent to it, and exercising faith in God’s word.

***“For this cause also thank we God without ceasing, because, when ye received the word of God which ye heard of us, ye received it not as the word of men, but as it is in truth, the word of God, which effectually worketh also in you that believe” (1 Thessalonians 2:13 KJV)***

Paul writes to commend the Christians in Thessalonica for their faith during persecution (chapter 3 verse 7).  The Thessalonians had heard and received the word of God (‘notitia’), had assented to it as the truthful word of God (‘assensus’), and had placed their trust in what it was they had heard and assented to (‘fiducia’).

Here are a few Bible verses that form the basis for the Reformed Protestant definition of faith, showing how we must (1) understand what it is we are to have faith in, (2) assent to and approve of what faith demands of us and (3) have implicit faith and trust in God’s plans for our salvation.  All verses are taken from the King James Version of the Bible. (Emphasis my own)

> Romans 1:17: “For therein is the righteousness of God revealed from faith to faith: as it is written, “The just shall live by faith.”

> Romans 3:21-22; 27-28: “But now the righteousness of God...  ***which is by faith of Jesus Christ*** unto all and upon all them that believe...   Where is boasting then? It is excluded. By what law? of works? Nay, but by the law of faith.”

> Romans 5:1: “Therefore being justified by faith, we have peace with God through our Lord Jesus Christ.”

> Romans 10:17: ***“So then faith cometh by hearing, and hearing by the word of God.”***

> 2 Corinthians 5:7: “For we walk by faith, not by sight.”

> Ephesians 2:8-9: “For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: ***it is the gift of God: Not of works,*** lest any man should boast.”

> Hebrews 11:6: “But without faith it is impossible to please him: for ***he that cometh to God must believe that he is***, and that he is a rewarder of them that diligently seek him.”

> Hebrews 12:2: ***“Looking unto Jesus the author and finisher of our faith.”***

I believe that the Bible verses quoted above are self-explanatory, although I must add that our Reformed Protestant faith is centred upon faith in what God has done in Jesus Christ.

Additional source of information here: https://www.ligonier.org/learn/devotionals/three-aspects-of-faith

and here: https://www.ligonier.org/learn/devotionals/faith-defined